# Should the corners of a sliding patio door frame be caulked?

Tags: doors, caulking, sliding-glass-door

Should gaps in the outside corners of a sliding patio door's frame be caulked to prevent water infiltration, or left as-is?

[image: example gap]

Answer (score 2):

That should be caulked.

Some clear silicone should do the trick.

Comment: White would work too.

Comment: It's more important than it looks as the channel in the plastic will collect water across the entire door width and drain it into that gap. Mine was incorrectly installed as well and the water ended up in the wall below.